# Exclude blank values from dataset (GeoPosition)

Tags: filtering

Any idea how to filter this dataset to *exclude* blank values in `FlightPath`?

[image: Example Dataset with blank FlightPath Values]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load a representative dataset (in copy-paste-able form) so that potential respondents can experiment with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to exclude them why won't you delete positions where these appear. (or use it to apply `select` and `Cases` Methods)

```
ds = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "FlightPath" -> {1}|>, <|"a" -> 2, 
"b" -> "y", "FlightPath" -> {2, 3}|>, <|"a" -> 3, 
"b" -> "z"|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", 
"FlightPath" -> {4, 5}|>, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y"|>, <|"a" -> 6, 
"b" -> "z", "FlightPath" -> "2"|>} // Dataset;
```

[image]

```
pos = Position[ds[All, "FlightPath"], _Missing];
ds1 = ds[Delete[pos], All];
```

[image]